# Multiple Databases On Salesforce DE edition

Tags: database

I was wondering whether it is possible to have multiple databases associated with my current Salesforce DE account.

As I want to add some new data, but do not want to corrupt the current database that holds important data.
Hence I want to add new database.

i.e The end result should be I should have 2 databases.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it isn't possible. Either you can move your code/metadata to a new org and where you can create new data for you.